# GridView inside ListRow using Leanback library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-tv, leanback

Is there any way to do gridView inside ListRow in DetailsFragment or ListRowFragment? I'm trying make multipleviews fragment in Leanback.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Create one item for listrow presenter.And in the presenter create custom view or fragment and add items there.